# Context-Based Paragraph Splitting of an Article or long Text

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I want to chunk long text into paragraphs that are context-based, because right now i'm just splitting the text in to sentences and chunking them every 250 words and calling that a paragraph, but its obviously not a good way to make a paragraph because its "dumb" and information thats over 250 words gets kept out, and it isn't even really a paragraph, just all the sentences before 250 words is filled up. So i want to make context-based paragraph splitting so it "smart" and is actually a paragraph.

The code below is what i have now:

```
import re

newtext = '''
Kendrick Lamar Duckworth is an American rapper, songwriter, and record producer. He is often cited as one of the most influential rappers of his generation. Aside from his solo career, he is also a member of the hip hop supergroup Black Hippy alongside his former Top Dawg Entertainment (TDE) labelmates Ab-Soul, Jay Rock, and Schoolboy Q. Raised in Compton, California, Lamar embarked on his musical career as a teenager under the stage name K.Dot, releasing a mixtape titled Y.H.N.I.C. (Hub City Threat Minor of the Year) that garnered local attention and led to his signing with indie record label TDE. He began to gain recognition in 2010 after his first retail release, Overly Dedicated. The following year, he independently released his first studio album, Section.80, which included his debut single "HiiiPoWeR". By that time, he had amassed a large online following and collaborated with several prominent rappers. He subsequently secured a record deal with Dr. Dre's Aftermath Entertainment, under the aegis of Interscope Records. Lamar's major-label debut album, Good Kid, M.A.A.D City, was released in 2012, garnering him widespread critical recognition and mainstream success. His third album To Pimp a Butterfly (2015), which incorporated elements of funk, soul, jazz, and spoken word, predominantly centred around the Black-American experience. It became his first number-one album on the US Billboard 200 and was an enormous critical success. His fourth album, Damn (2017), saw continued acclaim, becoming the first non-classical and non-jazz album to be awarded the Pulitzer Prize for Music. It also yielded his first number-one single, "Humble", on the US Billboard Hot 100. Lamar curated the soundtrack to the superhero film Black Panther (2018) and in 2022, released his fifth and last album with TDE, Mr. Morale & the Big Steppers, which received critical acclaim. Lamar has certified sales of over 70 million records in the United States alone, and all of his albums have been certified platinum or higher by the Recording Industry Association of America (RIAA). He has received several accolades in his career, including 14 Grammy Awards, two American Music Awards, six Billboard Music Awards, 11 MTV Video Music Awards, a Pulitzer Prize, a Brit Award, and an Academy Award nomination. In 2012, MTV named him the Hottest MC in the Game on their annual list. Time named him one of the 100 most influential people in the world in 2016. In 2015, he received the California State Senate's Generational Icon Award. Three of his studio albums were included on Rolling Stone's 2020 list of the 500 Greatest Albums of All Time. Kendrick Lamar Duckworth was born in Compton, California on June 17, 1987, the son of a couple from Chicago. Although not in a gang himself, he grew up around gang members, with his closest friends being Westside Piru Bloods and his father, Kenny Duckworth, being a Gangster Disciple. His first name was given to him by his mother in honor of singer-songwriter Eddie Kendricks of The Temptations. He grew up on welfare and in Section 8 housing. In 1995, at the age of eight, Lamar witnessed his idols Tupac Shakur and Dr. Dre filming the music video for their hit single "California Love", which proved to be a significant moment in his life. As a child, Lamar attended McNair Elementary and Vanguard Learning Center in the Compton Unified School District. He has admitted to being quiet and shy in school, his mother even confirming he was a "loner" until the age of seven. As a teenager, he graduated from Centennial High School in Compton, where he was a straight-A student. Kendrick Lamar has stated that Tupac Shakur, the Notorious B.I.G., Jay-Z, Nas and Eminem are his top five favorite rappers. Tupac Shakur is his biggest influence, and has influenced his music as well as his day-to-day lifestyle. In a 2011 interview with Rolling Stone, Lamar mentioned Mos Def and Snoop Dogg as rappers that he listened to and took influence from during his early years. He also cites now late rapper DMX as an influence: "[DMX] really [got me started] on music," explained Lamar in an interview with Philadelphia's Power 99. "That first album [It's Dark and Hell Is Hot] is classic, [so he had an influence on me]." He has also stated Eazy-E as an influence in a post by Complex saying: "I Wouldn't Be Here Today If It Wasn't for Eazy-E." In a September 2012 interview, Lamar stated rapper Eminem "influenced a lot of my style" and has since credited Eminem for his own aggression, on records such as "Backseat Freestyle". Lamar also gave Lil Wayne's work in Hot Boys credit for influencing his style and praised his longevity. He has said that he also grew up listening to Rakim, Dr. Dre, and Tha Dogg Pound. In January 2013, when asked to name three rappers that have played a role in his style, Lamar said: "It's probably more of a west coast influence. A little bit of Kurupt, [Tupac], with some of the content of Ice Cube." In a November 2013 interview with GQ, when asked "The Four MC's That Made Kendrick Lamar?", he answered Tupac Shakur, Dr. Dre, Snoop Dogg and Mobb Deep, namely Prodigy. Lamar professed to having been influenced by jazz trumpeter Miles Davis and Parliament-Funkadelic during the recording of To Pimp a Butterfly. Lamar has been branded as the "new king of hip hop" numerous times. Forbes said, on Lamar's placement as hip hop's "king", "Kendrick Lamar may or may not be the greatest rapper alive right now. He is certainly in the very short lists of artists in the conversation." Lamar frequently refers to himself as the "greatest rapper alive" and once called himself "The King of New York." On the topic of his music genre, Lamar has said: "You really can't categorize my music, it's human music." Lamar's projects are usually concept albums. Critics found Good Kid, M.A.A.D City heavily influenced by West Coast hip hop and 90s gangsta rap. His third studio album, To Pimp a Butterfly, incorporates elements of funk, jazz, soul and spoken word poetry. Called a "radio-friendly but overtly political rapper" by Pitchfork, Lamar has been a branded "master of storytelling" and his lyrics have been described as "katana-blade sharp" and his flow limber and dexterous. Lamar's writing usually includes references to racism, black empowerment and social injustice, being compared to a State of Union address by The Guardian. His writing has also been called "confessional" and controversial. The New York Times has called Lamar's musical style anti-flamboyant, interior and complex and labelled him as a technical rapper. Billboard described his lyricism as "Shakespearean".    
'''
#1100 words
 
 

regex = r'([A-z][^.!?]*[.!?]*"?)'
for sens in re.findall(regex, newtext):
    newtext = newtext.replace(f'{sens}', f'{sens}<eos>')
    sentencess = newtext.split('<eos>')
sentences = sentencess

current_chunk = 0
chunks = []

for sentence in sentences:
    if len(chunks) == current_chunk + 1:
        if len(chunks[current_chunk]) + len(sentence.split(" ")) <= 250:
            chunks[current_chunk].extend(sentence.split(" "))
        else:
            current_chunk += 1
            chunks.append(sentence.split(" "))
    else:
        chunks.append(sentence.split(" "))
for chunk_id in range(len(chunks)):
    chunks[chunk_id] = " ".join(chunks[chunk_id])
print(chunks) # printing all split "paragraphs"
print(chunks[0]) # printing 1st "paragraph"
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to make paragraphs, that are context-based, out of a long piece of text, i'm sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: Show us some example input text, and the code you use to try to parse it in a context-based way, even if it's not yet working. For example, do you have quoted dialogue text in your input corpus? Does indentation introduce a new paragraph? Do you have any indented block quote material? Does blank line introduce a new paragraph? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hey Zeke, I feel like this is a very subjective problem with potentially several valid solutions. You might have a better chance getting feedback on something not on SO as well.

Comment: Give a look at this: https://medium.com/@npolovinkin/how-to-chunk-text-into-paragraphs-using-python-8ae66be38ea6